# Your Ruby version is 2.6.3, but your Gemfile specified ~> 2.3.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-5

I have checked my global version is till 2.3.1 but this error comes up whenever I do "bundle exec rails s"

[image: example image]

Comment: Delete the line specifying the Ruby version from your Gemfile and try again.

Comment: Also don't forget to check/correct .ruby-version file if exists

Comment: Please do not post images of plaintext as [they are not appropriate on StackOverflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/3784008). Please copy and paste plaintext into your question.